# Навести фокус на input

Tags: css, jquery, вёрстка, bootstrap4

Не получается перекинуть автоматом фокус на `input` после нажатия на кнопку.

`onclick` находится в `html`

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="2hfp1SzUoho7/TsGGGDaFdsuuDL0LX2hnUp6VkX3CUQ2K4K+xjboZdsXyp4oUHZj" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="VjEeINv9OSwtWFLAtmc4JCtEJXXBub00gtSnszmspDLCtC0I4z4nqz7rEFbIZLLU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="btn-group w-100">
  <button type="button" class="btn border" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" onclick="$('#inputAutocompleteAccesses').focus();">Выбрать право</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu col-12 shadow text-center">
    <div class="container-fluid p-0">
      <div class="row m-0 p-0">
        <input class="form-control mx-2" oninput="sendRequestAccessJson($(this).val());" id="inputAutocompleteAccesses" placeholder="Введите право" />
      </div>
      <div id="autocompleteAccesses">

      </div>

      <div class="row mx-1 justify-content-center">
        <p>1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row mx-1 justify-content-center">
        <p>2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row mx-1 justify-content-center">
        <p>3</p>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

щас решил так:

```js
function f(){
  $('#inputAutocompleteAccesses').focus();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="2hfp1SzUoho7/TsGGGDaFdsuuDL0LX2hnUp6VkX3CUQ2K4K+xjboZdsXyp4oUHZj" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="VjEeINv9OSwtWFLAtmc4JCtEJXXBub00gtSnszmspDLCtC0I4z4nqz7rEFbIZLLU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="btn-group w-100">
  <button type="button" class="btn border" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" onclick="setTimeout(f, 10);">Выбрать право</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu col-12 shadow text-center">
    <div class="container-fluid p-0">
      <div class="row m-0 p-0">
        <input class="form-control mx-2" oninput="sendRequestAccessJson($(this).val());" id="inputAutocompleteAccesses" placeholder="Введите право" />
      </div>
      <div id="autocompleteAccesses">

      </div>

      <div class="row mx-1 justify-content-center">
        <p>1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row mx-1 justify-content-center">
        <p>2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row mx-1 justify-content-center">
        <p>3</p>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

но все же как правильно????????

Comment: У вас не работает `focus()` из-за ошибки! Используйте стабильные версии.

Comment: и зачем же мешать js код с html ?

Comment: @teran заетм, что это только нужная чать кода, которая воспроизводит мою проблему...

Comment: @doox911 какой ошибки?? `focus` отрабатывает во втором примере....мож я что то не так понял..можно по подробнее ? о версиях чего идет речь?? `jQuery`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте события [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#events).

```js
$('#myDropdown').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function () {
  $(this).find('input').trigger('focus');
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Example split danger button -->
<div id="myDropdown" class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Action</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split strelka" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <div  class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">1</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">2</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">3</a>
    <div class="dropdown-item">
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Введите право">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```